# Add custom action in Wix with multiple dependencies

Tags: c#, wix, npgsql, custom-action

I have a problem when trying to add a custom action in Wix with C# DLL.
I have a custom action for checking the Postgresql server connection and in the C# project, I use `Npgsql` for checking it.
Everything is ok with `Npgsql` ver `3.1.0`.
But when I upgrade `Npgsql` to ver `5.0.3` (the lastest ver), build the MSI installer again, hit the button to run the custom-action, an error occurred

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions'
```

I know that with the new version it required `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`.
But I don't know how to embedded into my custom-action DLL.

These are the dependencies of ver `5.0.3`:
[image]

Updated, this is the full logs when error happened

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool..ctor(NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, String connString)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at OmsCustomAction.OmsCustomActions.TestConnection(PGInfo pgServer, String& error) in C:\OPSWAT\sf-core\wix-setup\OmsCustomAction\OmsCustomAction\OmsCustomAction.cs:line 263

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/eckkom/AppData/Local/Temp/MSI7CB0.tmp-
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : System.Threading.Channels, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\eckkom\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI7CB0.tmp-\CustomAction.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/eckkom/AppData/Local/Temp/MSI7CB0.tmp-/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Updated Mar-24-2021:
Maybe it is a bug of `Npgsql`
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's maybe a bug of `Npgsql`: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677

But I finally found a solution to this.
Just create a config file `app.config` or modify your existing `.config` file like this

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.1" newVersion="5.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Channels" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

For the version of the packages, check it in your project's reference
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. And details appeared to be important. In addition to the answer above:

Somehow Nuget created `App.config` file and added binding redirects to `App.config` with `Build Action` set to `None`, but there is a `CustomAction.config` which contains different binding redirects. After deleting App.Config and moving binding redirects from it to `CustomAction.config` it worked.
It's also important to mention that `Build action` for the `*.config` file should be set to `Content`. `Copy to output Directory` - `Do not Copy`.